# UV & IR radiation are mostly absorbed by water. Our eyes are predominantly water. If our eyes were made of another liquid, could we see slight UV/IR?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, dielectric, vision, infrared-radiation

Firstly, I'm not a physics guy. I just think it's neat, that's all.

I was reading a post on here about why water is transparent (I was more interested in why *milk isn't*) and saw a graph that showed how water is opaque at other ranges of light, specifically deepUV and infrared. As I read the post with my water-based vision orbs, I started to wonder: If my eyes were made of another liquid, some kind of science-fiction compound that didn't absorb UV and IR radiation, could I possibly see those colors? I remember reading an article about the human eye being able to perceive down to around 1000nm wavelengths, in the near-IR range, triggered by "two-photon chromophore isomerization." I wonder how much more effective that would be if the light wasn't absorbed by the water in our eyes...

Comment: People affected by Aphakia (born without a lens for their eyes), can see extremely limited UV as a bluish haze around objects. I say this because some UV/infrared does penetrate into water of course.

Answer (score 1):

No. Over distances of order $1cm$ the absorption by water of near IR varies from about 1/1000 nearest the visible spectrum to near complete absorption at the low frequency end of near IR. For near UV it is about the same as for visible light. Assuming you had a broad spectrum detector, you wouldn't notice any difference in the near UV by replacing water with vacuum, and the difference in brightness in the nearest parts of the IR spectrum would be just barely noticeable.

[image]

Image from: Ozaki, Yukihiro & Morisawa, Yusuke & Ikehata, Akifumi & Higashi, Noboru. (2012). Far-Ultraviolet Spectroscopy in the Solid and Liquid States: A Review. Applied Spectroscopy. 66. 1-25. 10.1366/11-06496.